# Using Ito's Lemma to derive $\int^{T}_0 W_tdW_t =\frac{1}{2} W_{T}^2-\frac{1}{2} T$ where $W_t$ is brownian motion and $W_t=0$

Tags: brownian-motion

Using Ito's Lemma, derive $$\int^{T}_0 W_tdW_t =\frac{1}{2}  W_{T}^2-\frac{1}{2} T$$
where $W_t$ is brownian motion and $W_t=0$

---

**Appreciate a hint ; dont know where to start.**

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: try applying Ito's lemma to $X_t=f(t,W_t)$ for $f(t,x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(W_T)=\int_{0}^{T}f'(W_t)dW_t+\frac 12 \int_{0}^{T}f''(W_t) dt$$
Set $f(x)=x^2$ thus
$$W_T^2=2\int_0^T W_t dW_t+ \int_0^T dt=2\int_0^T W_t dW_t + T$$